# Why isset post doesn't work with ajax search using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the problem with search using PHP and AJAX. Currently, when I type something, then I see only numbers in console and `echo` doesn't work.

If I delete `if (isset($_POST['invite'])) {` and type whatever, then `echo` display users, but search doesn't work.

Where I made a mistake?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#invite_cc').keyup(function() {
    var query = $(this).val();
    if (query != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'form-search-user.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{query:query},
        success: function(response) {
          $('#invite_result_cc').html(response);
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**form-search-user.php**

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysql/config.php');

if (isset($_POST['invite'])) {

  $invite_rows_cc = $db->QueryGetNumRows("SELECT * FROM user_about WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$_POST['invite']."%' OR lastname LIKE '%".$_POST['invite']."%' LIMIT 5");
  $invite_value_cc = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT * FROM user_about WHERE firstname LIKE '%".$_POST['invite']."%' OR lastname LIKE '%".$_POST['invite']."%' LIMIT 5");

  if ($invite_rows_cc > 0) {

    foreach ($invite_value_cc as $key) {
      echo "
      <div class='invite_search_cont'>
        <div class='invite_search_img'><img src='{$key['profile_image']}'></img></div>
        <div class='invite_search_name'>{$key['firstname']} {$key['lastname']}</div>
      </div>
      ";
    }

  } else {

    echo 'No results';

  }

}
```

HTML

```
<input type='text' name='invite' value='' id='invite_cc' placeholder='Search' class='form-control'>
<div id='invite_result_cc'></div>
```

Comment: In your ajax call you have `data:{query:query}` and you are checking `$_POST['invite']`

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending anything named 'invite' in you post array:

```
data:{query:query}
```

You can fix that by adding the proper key: value pair:

```
data:{query:query, invite:'invite'}
```

Now `$_POST['invite']` will be set to 'invite'. You can use whatever variable value you would like. For example:

```
if (isset($_POST['invite']) && 'invite' == $_POST['invite'])...
```

**EDIT** I can see now you intend `$_POST['invite']` to contain the search value, so make the following changes to your AJAX:

```
data:{invite :query}
```

This set the name of the variable `$_POST['invite']` and makes that array variable's value the value of `query`

Comment: mate, you're missing a `'` in `'invite == $_POST['invite']`

Comment: Thanks @Cemal. The syntax highlighter was doing its job, but my coffee still hasn't kicked in, so I kept staring at it and not registering the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (isset($_POST['invite'])) {
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
```

Comment: The OP needs to change this everywhere the use `$_POST['invite']`